Angular 18, main.ts:8 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_AppComponent])[ActivatedRoute -> ActivatedRoute -> ActivatedRoute]:
Im trying to setUp a Router, RouterLink on my Angular project, and I keep constantly getting the next error on the website console:
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_AppComponent])[ActivatedRoute -> ActivatedRoute -> ActivatedRoute]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRoute!
    at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:1636:21)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3018:27)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3018:27)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3018:27)
    at ChainedInjector.get (core.mjs:5289:32)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.mjs:5632:31)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:5678:10)
    at ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.mjs:11577:17)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.RouterLink_Factory [as factory] (router.mjs:6172:85)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:5872:38)

Here is how my code
app.routes.ts:
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {HomeComponent} from './components/home/home.component';
import {ArtistasPageComponent} from './components/artistas-page/artistas-page.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'artistas', component: ArtistasPageComponent},
  { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home'},
];


app.config.ts
import { ApplicationConfig, provideZoneChangeDetection } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(routes)]
};


app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterLink, RouterLinkActive, RouterOutlet} from '@angular/router';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {HeaderComponent} from './components/header/header.component';
import {NavbarComponent} from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import {FooterComponent} from './components/footer/footer.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, RouterLink, RouterLinkActive, HeaderComponent, NavbarComponent, FooterComponent],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app-ProyectoArt';
}


app.component.html
<app-header></app-header>

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ANGULAR</a>

  <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/artistas" routerLinkActive="active" >Artistas</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="">Listas</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>


And I dont know if this is important or if something should go here, but here is the home.Component.ts for reference
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrl: './home.component.scss'
})
export class HomeComponent {}


I have been all morning trying everything I could to make this work, looking on previous projects, following the Angular Routes Documentation, watching for people with who got the same error. But nothing seems to work, I always end up with this error.
I tried adding RouterModule.forRoot(routes) in AppComponent, but I get errors.
If someone can see what am I doing wrong I would be really grateful.
------------UPDATE---------------
I watched my Main.ts again and saw some differences from a clean project I made to check things, and noticed it was different, so I tried something and at least Routes works again.
Main.ts looks like this now.
/// <reference types="@angular/localize" />

import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import {provideHttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {appConfig} from './app/app.config';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers:[
    provideHttpClient()
  ]})
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));


bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));


On the otherside now I cant connect to the Api I was using HttpClient for, but I guess thats because something I touched trying to fix Routes. Curiously enought, im getting the same Error code. So probably the main problem was with Main.ts on the first place, lets see If I can manage to finish this up.

Someone told me to change the name of the Title, what should it be like?

related to title, you can define in routes, see the doc or 1.-import {Title} from '@angular/platform-browser', 2.-in constructor constructor(private title:Title){} 3.-and where you want:this.title.setTitle("new Title").

You are bootstrapping the application twice in your main.ts, with different configs. Remove the first call to the bootstrapApplication() function:
/// <reference types="@angular/localize" />

import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import {provideHttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {appConfig} from './app/app.config';


bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

To make your HTTP client working, add provideHttpClient() to your app.config.ts:
import { ApplicationConfig, provideZoneChangeDetection } from '@angular/core';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideHttpClient(),
  ]
};


Thanks, this managed to finally fix my project, everything is working properly now, It was a bad idea to inicialize bootstrapAplication twice, when I can just add HttpClient to app.config. Again, im really grateful for you to take the time and help me! Thanks.

While using ActivatedRoute in your standalone component, you need to import RouterModule in the decoration section of component.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  imports: [
     RouterModule,
     ...
  ],
})
export class AppComponent {
/** content of your component */
}

